# How to process a javascript function call that returns a string with quotes in it

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with a javascript call to an api function in NetSuite that returns a string with quotes in it. An error is thrown each time the call is made.

```
var selling_point_1 = "<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitemsellingpoint1')%>";
```

when looking in the debugger, this evaluates to:

```
var selling_point_1 = "Product Dimensions: H:14" W:24"";
```

Any string function (like .length or charAt(0) ) on this also throws an error. I have no control over what the function call returns, so i need to know how to handle embedded quotes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, John

Comment: Trivial solution for this case: use single outer quotes, not double quotes. Suggestion for general solution: does your server-side lanuage (ASP? -- tag it please) have some kind of `escape` function?

Comment: If you identify your server-side language, I can probably provide you with an ideal solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's ASP. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not the most robust method you could use:

```
var selling_point_1 = escape("<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitemsellingpoint1')%>");
```

This is actually for URI escaping, but will get rid of the pesky double quotes, plus you can use unescape to get the original format back. As suggested

```
var selling_point_1 = '<%=getCurrentAttribute(\'item\',\'custitemsellingpoint1\')%>';
```

Should also work in your case.

Comment: good suggestions. By using the single quotes around the function call and then my subsequent document.write call, this worked. I don't want to get rid of the double quotes, they represent the length of a product in inches. The only problem is that i can also have single quotes embebed in the string (representing feet). so i need a little more robust solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t70655-escape-function-in-asp-net.html) for someone dealing with roughly the same issue.  The short answer is that you need to run some kind of escape function in the *server-side* code (i.e., within the `<%=...%>` block) so that only escaped values get inserted into the client-side code.  All of the solutions below can handle an unlimited number of single and double quotes.

My first suggestion is to try:

```
var selling_point_1 = decodeURI("<%=Server.URLEncode(getCurrentAttribute('item','custitemsellingpoint1'))%>");
```

This will produce server-side JS that looks like:

```
var selling_point_1 = decodeURI("Product Dimensions: H:14%22 W:24%22");
```

The `decodeURI` JavaScript function will convert the `%22` back into quotes and the correct string will be stored in `selling_point_1`.

**If that fails**, you might also try something like:

```
var selling_point_1 = unescape("<%=HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(getCurrentAttribute('item','custitemsellingpoint1'))%>");
```

which operates similarly, but tuuns your quotes into `\"` sequences, which will be converted back into ordinary quotes by JavaScript's `unescape`.